# Patterns for words with "iev" and "eiv"

Tags: orthography

I usually misspell words like "believe" or "receive". For words like these two I would usually google it first to see if I got the spelling right. Is there a pattern for words like these?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [old saying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_before_E_except_after_C) goes like this:

> i before e except after c
>   or when sounded like a
>   as in neighbor and weigh

While this rule covers a large number of words, of course, there are a ton of exceptions (neither, height, weird, etc.).

Comment: Thanks. Just what I was looking for. XD Can't believe I missed this.

Comment: "seize" is another exception. We learnt the rule as "I before E, except after C, when the sound is EE", which at least means that height/sleight are not exceptions :)

Comment: And also "Kiev".

Comment: I'm relatively sure we're not considering proper nouns from non-English speaking countries.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy rule for this spelling.

The rote saying "i before e except after c" is no longer taught in British schools as there are over 900 exceptions and these exceptions outnumber those that conform to the rule by 75%. You should look at

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_before_E_except_after_C which shows that the desperate attempt to force the "rule" to work becomes so complex that it is useless

and

https://www.rd.com/article/i-before-e-rule/ that goes into the statistics.

Answer (score -1):

In case of eiv and iev, when there is sound of 'c' then the following pattern will be eiv (alphabetical order). For example: deceive, receive, perceive.

However, when there is other sound than 'c', for instance, believe, achieve (now the order is iev because there is no sound of 'c').